# Get Kotlin Flow value instantly

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow

> I have to fetch some api for a screen. After completing all calls I have to show their data, Both their **ApiRequestStatus** and **ResponseData** are flows .

```
       viewModelScope.launch {
            val requestStateFlows = arrayListOf(
                bonusGiftApiRequestStateFlow,
                personalOffersApiRequestStateFlow,
                favoriteOffersApiRequestStateFlow,
            ).filterNotNull()
            combine(
                requestStateFlows
            ) { requests ->
                _isDynamicDataLoaded.value =
                    requests.all { it?.status == ApiRequestStatus.COMPLETED }
            }.collect()
        }

    private val _isDynamicDataLoaded = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val isDynamicDataLoaded = _isDynamicDataLoaded.asStateFlow()
```

When **isDynamicDataLoaded** is **true** like

```
viewModel.isDynamicDataLoaded.collect { allDataLoaded ->
   /// I want to call all data flows instantly and populate at once. 
}
```

But don't know how to call them at once.. Example of flows are

```
val personalOffers: Flow<List<PersonalOffer>> get() = PersonalOffersRepository.instance.getPersonalOffers()
val favoriteOffersLiveData: Flow<List<DBProduct>> get() = ProductsRepository.instance.getFavoriteOfferProductsLiveData().asFlow()
```

I want above personalOffers and favoriteOffersLiveData instantly when

```
isDynamicDataLoaded is true.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
viewModel.isDynamicDataLoaded.collect { allDataLoaded ->
    if (allDataLoaded) {
        combine(personalOffers, favoriteOffersLiveData) { personal, favorite ->
            // Use both personal and favorite data as you wish here
          
        }.collect {
            // Do something with the combined data
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A nested collect call in a collect call is a smell. Once the inner `collect` starts, it will never return and so the outer collect will never see the next item.

Answer (score 1):

To call multiple flows instantly and populate at once in Kotlin, you can use the combineLatest() operator.

```
viewModelScope.launch {
  combineLatest(
      personalOffers(),
      favoriteOffersLiveData().asFlow()
  ) { personalOffers, favoriteOffers ->
    // Show the personal offers.
    // ...

    // Show the favorite offers.
    // ...
  }
}
```